# Show day, month and year with std::chrono?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I read that I can show the current day, month and year with [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) but how I can do that?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  cout << std::chrono::day;
}
```

I do this code but it doesn't work, I always receive this

```
 error: 'day' is not a member of 'std::chrono
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: day is part of (C++20)

Comment: [(reference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/day)

Comment: You can enjoy this part of C++20 today with [this library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) is what you need:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>    

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now), "%Y-%m-%d") << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

> 2018-05-14

Comment: On Visual Studio 2017 I'm getting deprecated for localtime and it offers me to use localtime_s instead, which requires 2 parameters. With localtime_s put_time doesn't work. ):

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman I feel for you. [`std::localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) *is not deprecated* and is defined by the Standard. Shame (again) on MSVC.

Comment: the exact error I'm getting is: `Function 'localtime' is deprecated, reason: 'This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.` Why Microsoft follows different standards? D:

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman because it's Microsoft - they have their own `_s` versions of a number of C-style API functions, like memcpy, strcpy, etc.

Comment: @hauron but why they're trying to reinvent the wheel? Are those functions really unsafe?

Comment: @YSC I think you should be thankful instead of shaming MS for providing thread safe alternative, which standard omits

Comment: @kill between providing a thread-safe version and deprecating a standard function, there is a gap I mind about.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman they're supposed to be safer, as you need to explicitly provide the size of both the destination and source. Supposedly, less space for error. It seems to be standard to enforce use of these in SDL.

Comment: @YSC Yes it is annoying, but in this case it is shame on CPP committee

Answer (score 2):

A different approach based on [std:strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::tm ptm;
    localtime_s(&ptm, &now_c);
    char buffer[80];
    std::strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ", &ptm);
    std::cout << buffer;
}
```

Result:

> 2018-05-14 19:33:11

(`localtime_s` is outside of std namespace and uses a slightly different interface)